# Dynamically infer generic types via. reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0

Any help would be appreciated on this one. I'm trying to implement a dynamic object wrapper over  a static type. This wrapper should then allow me to call static functions dynamically at run time.

For example:

```
dynamic obj = new StaticDynamicWrapper(typeof(MyStaticType));
obj.DoSomething(arg1);
```

That's the idea. I got some online reference to get it to work on non-generic method and property but ran into various issues when "DoSomething" is actually a generic method.

For example, if the declaration of the "DoSomething" were as follow:

```
public static RetType DoSomething<TArg>(this TArg arg1);
```

Or even worse if do something were to have an overload with the following signature...

```
public static RetType DoSomething<TArg>(this OtherGenericType<AnotherGenericType<TArg>> arg1);
```

So I need to implement the DynamicObject.TryInvokeMember in such a way that the method invokation is able to infer at runtime, based on the runtime arguments (ie. object[] args), the correct closed generic method of DoSomething. In another word I wanna be able to select the correct overload and determines the correct type arguments to call MakeGenericMethod with, all that at runtime.

The biggest roadblock so far, is figuring out how to map the method's open generic arguments to the closed types arguments declared by the parameter arguments (ie. object[] args). Can anyone out there help me out?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I was thinking this could be done using either `Expression`s or `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder` that's used behind the scenes for `dynamic`, but I didn't find anything that would work.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Sometimes people come here trying to solve problem `X`, they present to us solution `Y` and have questions about it, but really, it turns out, there is a much better way to solve `X`. So, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a flexible AOP framework. I want the cross cutting advice to be statically typed, but the weaver itself more fluid, aka. dynamic. Yes there are other ways, such as adding a bunch of interfaces, etc., but when there are large swath of classes, that has to implement the interface, many of which are 3rd party, being able call functions dynamically is highly desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLR will infer method overloads including generics. The open source framework [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) available via nuget simplifies the [dlr calls to single method calls](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#Introduction) and does all the work for you. Infact it has a base class [ImpromptuForwarder](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageDynamic#ImpromptuForwarder) that will do this with a small constructor change.

```
using ImpromptuInterface;
using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic;
public class StaticDynamicWrapper:ImpromptuForwarder{
    public StaticDynamicWrapper(Type target):base(InvokeContext.CreateStatic(target)){
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this looks very promising! However I would like to avoid external dependencies if I could avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

By reading the code of ImpromptuInterface mentioned in jbtule's answer, you can do it using DLR something like this:

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(
    InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    var innerBinder = Binder.InvokeMember(
        CSharpBinderFlags.None, binder.Name, null, null,
        new[]
        {
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(
                CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType
                | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
        });
    var callSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>
        .Create(innerBinder);
    try
    {
        result = callSite.Target(callSite, m_type, args[0]);
        return true;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code works only for methods with one argument. If you want to support more of them, you have to put more `CSharpArgumentInfo`s into the collection, create `CallSite` with the appropriate number of arguments for the `Func` delegate and then call it. (`ImpromptuInterface` uses a `switch` for that.)

Comment: The switch case in impromptu is an optimization that handles up to 14 arguments after that it emits a delegate matching the number of arguments.  Another thing impromptu does for performance is reuse the callsite where it can--which increases the performance significantly. To get the benefits of the dlr's three-level cache you must reuse either the callsite or the binder.

Comment: Awesome this is what I'm looking for svick and jbtule you guys rock! :D

Answer (score 2):

For anyone out there who needs this feature, but don't wanna or cannot afford adding external dependencies to their project, the following may help you. It's no where near as robust as the impromptu solution, but may be just what you need. It's only good up to 9 arguments (I think, whatever is the max static arguments of System.Func type).

Use it at **your own risk**. Tested to work in my computer for my purposes only! ;)

```
public class StaticDynamicWrapper : DynamicObject
{    
    private Type _type;

    public StaticDynamicWrapper(Type type) { _type = type; }

    private static readonly IList< Func<Type, string, object[],object>> CallSiteInvokers;

    /// <summary>
    /// Static initializer. Used to improve performance so we only need to resolve the right Func type, once.
    /// </summary>
    static StaticDynamicWrapper()
    {
        CallSiteInvokers = new List< Func< Type, string, object[],object>>();

        //Get the max number of arguments allowed by the built in Func types.
        var funcTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Func<>)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Func`"))
            .Concat(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,>)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Func`")))
            .OrderBy(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Count()).ToArray();
        int maxNoOfArgs = funcTypes.Max(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Length) - 2; //We need to subtract 3 from the absolute max to account for the return type and the 2 required parameters: callsite and target type. Plus 1 to offset the indexing

        //Index the function calls based on the number of parameters in the arguments.
        for(int i = 0; i < maxNoOfArgs; i++)
        {
            int funcIndex = i + 2;

            CallSiteInvokers.Add
                (
                    ( type, name ,objects) =>
                        {
                            //The call site pre/post fixes.
                            var funcGenericArguments = new List<Type>() { typeof(CallSite), typeof(object), typeof(object) };

                            //The argument info collection
                            var argumentInfoCollection = new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>()
                                           {
                                               CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(
                                                   CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType |
                                                   CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType,
                                                   null)
                                           };

                            //Set up the generic arguments for objects passed in.
                            funcGenericArguments.InsertRange(2,objects.Select(o => o.GetType()));
                            //Set up the argument info for the inner binder.
                            argumentInfoCollection.AddRange(objects.Select(o=> CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)));
                            var innerBinder = Binder.InvokeMember(
                                CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, null, null, argumentInfoCollection.ToArray()                                    
                            );

                            //Dynamically instantiate the generic CallSite, by calling on the "Create" factory method.
                            var callSite = typeof (CallSite<>)
                                .MakeGenericType(
                                    funcTypes[funcIndex]
                                    .MakeGenericType(funcGenericArguments.ToArray())
                                )
                                .GetMethod("Create")
                                .Invoke(null,new object[]{innerBinder});

                            //Dynamically invoke on the callsite target.
                            object invokingDelegate = callSite.GetType().GetField("Target").GetValue(callSite);

                            return invokingDelegate.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(invokingDelegate,
                                new object[]
                                                {
                                                    callSite, 
                                                    type
                                                }.Concat(objects).ToArray());                                       

                        }
                );
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Handle static property accessors.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="binder"></param>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = _type.GetProperty(binder.Name, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);        
        if (prop == null)
        {
            result = null;            
            return false;
        }         
        result = prop.GetValue(null, null);        
        return true;
    }   

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle static methods
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="binder"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        try
        {
            result = CallSiteInvokers[args.Length](_type, binder.Name, args);
            return true;
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Just so that you know, there are `Func` delegate types with 1–8 arguments in the mscorlib assembly and then there are additional `Func` types with 9–16 arguments in System.Core.

Comment: Thanks! Modified accordingly.